# Cauchy-Riemann equations hold but function is not complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have the following function:

$$f(z)=f(x+iy)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^3(1-i)+y^3(1+i)}{x^2+y^2} , & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
0, & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

I have shown that for the above function, Cauchy-Riemann equations hold at $\left( 0,0\right)$.
I am now asked to show that this function is not complex differentiable at $(0,0)$.
I tried to calculate the limit:
$$ \lim_{z\to 0} \cfrac{f(z)-f(0) }{z-0}= \lim_{z\to 0} \cfrac{f(z) }{z}$$

So I tried to disprove the existence of this limit by trying several paths $\sigma (t)$
but the limit on all the paths I tried turned to exist and equal $1-i$.
Can anyone give me a hint on how can I show that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Try l'Hôpital rule!

Comment: Take limits along $y=x$ and $y=0$. Along $y=x$ you get $\frac 1 {1+i}$.